# WPF DataGrid: CellEditingTemplate ComboBox multiple data to CellTemplate TextBox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox, celltemplate, celleditingtemplate

I have googled around but with very limited luck. I have a question regarding editable WPF DataGrid; in a CellEditingTemplate a ComboBox is shown, but in CellTemplate a TextBox with corresponding ComboBox value is shown. My code looks something like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Unit">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ComboBox Name="comboBoxUnit" ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" SelectedValue="{Binding UnitId, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" SelectedValuePath="Id">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
              <TextBlock Text=" " />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="<would like to have selected Unit's Id and Name here>"  />
    </DataTemplate>                                    
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How can I achieve this? Separate property in a class (to have UnitId and UnitName properties) is not a problem, I can add it, but how to bind both to ComboBox then? Can I access CellEditingTemplate ComboBox in CellTemplate? It seems like they are in "different namespaces" since I can name controls in both with same names...

Any ideas, pointers? Thanks in advance,
DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve the same thing is to use a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

However, in my current project we had so many problems with the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` that we don't use it anymore. Instead we use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `ComboBox` in the `CellEditingTemplate` and a `TextBlock` in the `CellTemplate` *(just like you're doing)*.

To be able to display data based on an Id (to get the same functionality in the `TextBlock` as in the `ComboBox`) we use a converter called `CodeToDescriptionConverter`. It's usable like this

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <con:CodeToDescriptionConverter CodeAttribute="Id"
                                                StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                    <con:CodeToDescriptionConverter.DescriptionAttributes>
                        <sys:String>Id</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>Name</sys:String>
                    </con:CodeToDescriptionConverter.DescriptionAttributes>
                </con:CodeToDescriptionConverter>
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding Path="UnitId"/>
            <Binding Path="Units"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

- The first `Binding` is the value we look for (Id)
- The second `Binding` is the `IList` we look in
- `CodeAttribute` is the name of the property we want to compare to the id (first `Binding`)
- `DescriptionAttributes` are the properties we want to return formatted as `StringFormat`

And in your case: Find the instance in `Units` where the property `Id` has the same value as `UnitId` and for this instance return the values of `Id` and `Name` formatted as `{0} - {1}`

`CodeToDescriptionConverter` uses reflection to achieve this

```
public class CodeToDescriptionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public string CodeAttribute { get; set; }
    public string StringFormat { get; set; }
    public List<string> DescriptionAttributes { get; set; }

    public CodeToDescriptionConverter()
    {
        StringFormat = "{0}";
        DescriptionAttributes = new List<string>();
    }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 2 ||
            values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue ||
            values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue ||
            values[0] == null ||
            values[1] == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string code = values[0].ToString();
        IList sourceCollection = values[values.Length - 1] as IList;
        object[] returnDescriptions = new object[DescriptionAttributes.Count];
        foreach (object obj in sourceCollection)
        {
            PropertyInfo codePropertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(CodeAttribute);
            if (codePropertyInfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Code Property " + CodeAttribute + " not found");
            }
            string codeValue = codePropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
            if (code == codeValue)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < DescriptionAttributes.Count; i++)
                {
                    string descriptionAttribute = DescriptionAttributes[i];
                    PropertyInfo descriptionPropertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(descriptionAttribute);
                    if (descriptionPropertyInfo == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Description Property " + descriptionAttribute + " not found");
                    }
                    object descriptionObject = descriptionPropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
                    string description = "";
                    if (descriptionObject != null)
                    {
                        description = descriptionPropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
                    }
                    returnDescriptions[i] = description;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        // Ex. string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", arg1, arg2, arg3);
        return string.Format(StringFormat, returnDescriptions);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

I uploaded a sample application here: [CodeToDescriptionSample.zip](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39657172/CodeToDescriptionSample.zip).
It includeds a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with `CodeToDescriptionConverter` and a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` that does the same thing. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer. The included sample seems to do exactly what I want. I'll try to include your code into my project tomorrow and send feedback then.

Comment: Works as expected, very nice and universal solution! It showed me many things about value converters that I didn't know. I tried to send Units collection through ConverterParameter but binding doesn't work with converter parameters, so I stopped looking there...

Comment: Glad it helped you :) Yeah, you can't bind the `ConverterParameter` because it isn't a `DependencyPropety`. And if you make the converter inherit from `DependencyObject` so it can have `DependencyProperties` you run into the next problem. It isn't in the tree so `DataContext`, `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` `Bindings` doesn't work, only `Source`. It's just easiest to send it in as a second `Binding` :)